# why is docker run through jenkins job is failing but same runs without issue when run locally

Tags: .net, linux, docker, powershell, dockerfile

I have few powershell scripts that I need to containerize and run it through jenkins.
I created docker image with content like:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/powershell:latest
RUN pwsh -Command "Install-Module -Name <name> -Force -AllowClobber -Scope CurrentUser"
WORKDIR /app
COPY . .
ENV PSModulePath="/root/.local/share/powershell/Modules:${PSModulePath}"
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y sshpass
ENTRYPOINT ["pwsh","-command"]
```

and running docker image to run the main powershell script.

when I run locally, its working fine and as expected but when I run the same from jenkins job, it fails immediately after downloading the image from repo with this error:
`Failed to create CoreCLR, HRESULT: 0x80070008`

it looks to be dotnet error and I tried to integrate the same in dockerfile but still seeing same error. also tried to limit the memory to 2g, didnt help.

I cannot do much on jenkins slave so need to handle it from the job only.

when I run locally, its working fine and as expected but when I run the same from jenkins job, it fails immediately after downloading the image from repo with this error:
`Failed to create CoreCLR, HRESULT: 0x80070008`

Comment: What type of machine is the remote?  If remote is Linux or Mac this may be reason for failure.  Most likely the remote machine is using CORE if Linux or Mac.  See : https://devblogs.microsoft.com/powershell/powershell-6-0-roadmap-coreclr-backwards-compatibility-and-more/

Comment: I'm using Linux. CORE is used. from the blog, all I can understand is to report on github unless there was something else that I missed.

Comment: Try installing Tracer : https://docs.datadoghq.com/tracing/trace_collection/dd_libraries/dotnet-core/?tab=containers